# Running scripts resetting active cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm fairly new to Google Scripts, and I'd like to use onEdit to trigger a function whenever a cell is edited. While I've got it working, it resets the active cell to A1 when it runs, so if someone tries to enter more than one value at a time, e.g. cells C4, D4, E4) - while they are entering a value into E4 the selection will reset to A1.

Cheers

Edit: [Here's a spreadsheet showing the problem.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x_uwEPGgy5aqhtZXC-NwDU4Rh32Jqv2aK2rkIgAIjPM/edit?usp=sharing)

On further inspection, it looks like running any script (I also have a delete row function and an insert row function) will reset active cell to A1. This may not be the technical term, but if you have for example D4 selected, then running a script will change selection to A1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without knowing your code there is nowhere to begin with. `onEdit()` by itself does not change the active cell, it's something you are doing with the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you're resetting the active sheet, which reloads the page when the script is triggered.

Here's your current code:

```
// Get the active workbook
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get the first sheet in the workbook
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// Reload that first sheet
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
```

Remove the third line where `.setActiveSheet()` is called and the problem will go away.

Comment: that's brilliant, solved the problem immediately, thanks!